# Real time with variety of languages

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm looking for the best way for communicate web server with users. I try to explain:

I have a nodejs server. I need send information to each user, based on his ID. And the users respond with other info. Like a game, in real time, but they must be able to create a code for connect to my server.

Ok, I know way using nodejs with autobahn, subscribing to my server for getting info. But I need that users can send/receive info using javascript, python, java and other lenguages.
How to make publisher in server that can get/send the info in any language?

Comment: what about websocket?

Comment: Use AMQP with RabbitMQ, for example.

Comment: Any standard network protocol would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, any language can pretty much connect via HTTP, so there is Http long poling.

Even better there is websockets,  and a quick search seems to reveal most languages have websocket support.

There are also ready made rpc frameworks you could use.  Eg.  https://zeroc.com/products/ice